# Use google cloud translation with just a token and without keyfile

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

When using google cloud translation API I dont want to have to use a generated keyfile (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic?hl=de#node.js). We use docker containers deployed to some random host. I cannot add the keyfile to my source code to be compiled into the docker container for obvious security reasons and I dont want to have to copy a keyfile to every host to which the container is deployed (or might be deployed!)

Usually APIs are fine with a Token that I can set using my container management environment variables which I can then aply to all instances of the container when I have to scale it or switch hosts, etc. Does google offer that kind of setup? I'd be fine using REST requests, no need for any sdk.

The only alternative seems to me, adding the keyfile json as environment variable in our gitlab and then building the file into the container.

Or is there any other way of using the google translate API with just a token and no keyfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's SDK's can implicitly use the default service account (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

EDIT: This might solve your problem: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/185

Also: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#CredentialsFromJSON

Here's the code example:

```
json := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON") // `{"type": "service_account", "project_id": "my-project", ...}`
ctx := context.Background()
jwtConfig, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON([]byte(json), datastore.ScopeDatastore)
if err != nil {
    ...
}
ts := jwtConfig.TokenSource(ctx)
datastoreClient, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID, option.WithTokenSource(ts))
```

EDIT2:

Also check https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables

```
Loading credentials from environment variables
Instead of loading credentials from a key file, you can also provide them using an environment variable and the GoogleAuth.fromJSON() method. This is particularly convenient for systems that deploy directly from source control (Heroku, App Engine, etc).

Start by exporting your credentials:

$ export CREDS='{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "your-project-id",
  "private_key_id": "your-private-key-id",
  "private_key": "your-private-key",
  "client_email": "your-client-email",
  "client_id": "your-client-id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "your-cert-url"
}'
Now you can create a new client from the credentials:

const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');

// load the environment variable with our keys
const keysEnvVar = process.env['CREDS'];
if (!keysEnvVar) {
  throw new Error('The $CREDS environment variable was not found!');
}
const keys = JSON.parse(keysEnvVar);

async function main() {
  // load the JWT or UserRefreshClient from the keys
  const client = auth.fromJSON(keys);
  client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
  const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hmm.. it's just cumbersome. Or can I pass the json directly into GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS without having to create a file? Then I could just pass the json from build environment to the docker container and be done..

Comment: The spec says "First, ADC checks to see if the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set. If the variable is set, ADC uses the service account file that the variable points to. The next section describes how to set the environment variable." I agree it's not 100% optimal, but it's a fairly one-off thing to do.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/185

I appended it to my original answer as well.